Error in if (rfMetrics$f1 > best_rf_f1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed When perform Random Forest in R
I have this dataset
mydata=structure(list(crop_name = c("Guar", "Guar", "Guar", "Guar", 
    "Guar", "Guar", "Guar", "Guar", "Guar", "Guar", "Bajra", "Bajra", 
    "Bajra", "Bajra", "Bajra", "Bajra", "Bajra", "Bajra", "Bajra", 
    "Bajra"), B08A = c(2781L, 2817L, 2700L, 1780L, 3702L, 4094L, 
    3921L, 3780L, 2855L, 3501L, 2963L, 2578L, 1996L, 4502L, 4217L, 
    3528L, 3689L, 3529L, 3050L, 2996L), nir = c(2576L, 2607L, 2328L, 
    1541L, 3329L, 3681L, 3636L, 3382L, 2481L, 3174L, 2820L, 2691L, 
    2318L, 4229L, 3868L, 3648L, 3271L, 3244L, 2497L, 2752L), swir = c(2866L, 
    3589L, 2782L, 1447L, 2784L, 3084L, 3019L, 2972L, 1779L, 2687L, 
    3889L, 2332L, 1570L, 2574L, 2910L, 2546L, 2953L, 3176L, 3198L, 
    3464L), gcvi = c(0.624211853, 1.065768621, 0.897310513, 0.861111111, 
    1.384670487, 2.349408553, 2.246428571, 1.756316218, 1.753607103, 
    2.933085501, 0.923601637, 0.996290801, 2.274011299, 2.311667971, 
    3.084477296, 2.86031746, 2.494658119, 2.164878048, 1.824660633, 
    1.596226415)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L))

I'm trying to create a classifier that will predict which class of crop (bajra and guar) observation belong to. So the dependent variable is crop_name, the rest vars are predictors.
But I’m not just trying to create a classifier, I’m trying to automatically enumerate the hyperparameters of a random forest to achieve the accuracy I need (at least 90% by F-measure). Thus, the model must iterate over hyperparameters until the desired accuracy is achieved. (At the same time, if based on these predictors such accuracy is in principle not achievable, then provide the maximum achieved accuracy, for example it can be 70%).
Here are my attempts
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

# Convert the factor variable to a numeric one
mydata$crop_name <- as.numeric(mydata$crop_name) - 1

# We split the data into training and test samples
set.seed(123)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$crop_name, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
trainData <- mydata[trainIndex, ]
testData <- mydata[-trainIndex, ]

# Define a function to evaluate the model
evaluate_model <- function(model, testData) {
 predictions <- predict(model, testData)
 confusionMatrix <- confusionMatrix(data = factor(predictions, levels = c(0, 1)),
 reference = factor(testData$crop_name, levels = c(0, 1)),
 positive = "1")
 precision <- confusionMatrix$byClass['Pos Pred Value']
 recall <- confusionMatrix$byClass['Sensitivity']
 f1 <- 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
 return(list(precision = precision, recall = recall, f1 = f1))
}

# **Random Forest**

# Define a grid of parameters for searching
rfGrid <- expand.grid(mtry = c(2, 3, 4),
 ntree = c(500, 1000, 1500))

best_rf_f1 <- 0

# Enumerate random forest parameters
for (i in 1:nrow(rfGrid)) {
 # Model training
 rfModel <- randomForest(crop_name ~ ., data = trainData,
 mtry = rfGrid$mtry[i],
 ntree = rfGrid$ntree[i])

 # Model evaluation
 rfMetrics <- evaluate_model(rfModel, testData)

 # Save the model if the F1-measure is better than the previous ones
 if (rfMetrics$f1 > best_rf_f1) {
 best_rf_f1 <- rfMetrics$f1
 best_rf_model <- rfModel
 }
}
cat("Random Forest - F1-measure:", best_rf_f1, "\n")

however I get this error
Error in if (rfMetrics$f1 > best_rf_f1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?

What am I doing wrong? And how to correctly “force” the model
Iterate through your own hyperparameters until the desired accuracy, or the maximum possible accuracy, is achieved.
As usual, any help is greatly appreciated

What do you get for predictions? From that warning it seems to behave as a regressor and not classifier.

I'm afraid that this included mydata example is not that exact dataset your are testing with.  As mydata$crop_name type is character,  as.numeric(mydata$crop_name) - 1 results with a column of NAs, and you should get a warning for that.  And right after createDataPartition(mydata$crop_name, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) should fail with a missing values error. Besides, for classification with randomForest:: randomForest() you absolutely want your dependent var to be a factor, otherwise it switches to regression.
